# Sending millions of Mails using ThreadPool

Tags: c#, threadpool, bulk-mail

I have more than 100 million Mail IDs in my MySQL Database. I need to send E-Mails which is in HTML format to all those Mail IDs using thread pool. I cannot take that much datas in a single DataTable. So I think I can take 1000 Datas and after sending those 1000 Mails again take the next 1000. In that way I need to complete the Mailing Operation. I'm using 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' for communicating with MySQL Database

My Database Structure is

Columns:
ID - bigint,
MailID - varchar(300),
Unsubscribed - bit

I need to send mails to all Mail IDs with value 0 in Unsubscribed column.

Please help me how to do it in C#.

Comment: please give us more Details. Which DB Provider do you use. How do you Access the db. And WHAT exactly are you not able to implement in c# ? After that we could help you

Comment: Please do not use regional numerals like [_crore_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crore): the rest of the world will not understand that you mean (tens of) millions, or in this case "a lot". I have edited your question to replace it by _millions_ (and where you used 10 crore => 100 million)

Comment: i'm using 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' for communicating with database. My Database has 3 Columns, ID(bigint), MailID(varchar(300), Unsubscribed(bit). I need to send mails to all MailIDs having value in Unsubscribed as 0

Comment: @user2994846 please update your question with all additional information

Comment: I have updated my Question. Please help me out...

Comment: Please let me know you need any other information.

Comment: This looks like a repeat of an earlier question in the week.

Comment: If there is any same question resolved before, please forward me the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT * FROM Mails WHERE Unsibscribed=0 LIMIT 0,1000
 SELECT * FROM Mails WHERE Unsibscribed=0 LIMIT 1000,1000
 ...
```

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html
especially `LIMIT` clause.

also http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm

Comment: I've done like that. But how to do the thread pool operation in a loop. I need to take 1000 Mail IDs using a loop.

Comment: Why do you want to use the Threadpool. Do it single threaded asynchronous.

Comment: There are many examples for that on web, like http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667461/Send-asynchronous-mail-using-asp-net

Comment: I need to send all those mails within a short period of time. If we send 100 million mails using single thread, how long it will take to complete the operation?

Comment: When you call SendAsync then every single message is sent asynchronously. Try it and you will see if it is ok.

Comment: @VDohnal: Can we use SendAsync Method using a seperate thread?

Comment: I think so, but I am not sure if it improves the performance. I personally have never tried to send 100 millions of e-mails. I guess that the network communication with SMTP servers takes most of the time and that is already handled by SendAsync.

Comment: @VDohnal: I have tried with SendAsync method. When we run the function mails are given to send immediately. But it is taking the same time for the mail to get sent. Mails are getting sent one by one only. Actually I am looking for a solution with which I can send multiple mails at the same time (For example if it take 1 second for sending 1 mail, I need to send 10 or 100 mails in 1 second. That is why I thought about doing the operation using ThreadPool. Please tell me how can I do that one?

Comment: Good job! If you post a new question like this, I belive you get good response, your problem is quite clear now. I cannot help now, I am not on comp.